# Port 25 "relay send" and TLS

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

### Problem:

I have a Postfix server with dovecot running. Ports that are listening are `25`, `465` and  `993` where last two have a mandatory TLS. Other "email" ports are not listening.

This means that client's MUA must use port `465` for email *"submission"* and port `993` for email *"retrieval"*. This means one function per port *(nice)*.

Port `25` on the other hand has three functions i.e. email *"relay sending"* email *"relay recieving"* and email *"submitting"* *(a mess)*.

Other two ports are already demanding mandatory TLS and now I have to configure port `25` to do that as well. I know that Postfix is used to configure this port as it is SMTP port. I also understand that in `/etc/postfix/master.cf` I can use `-o` parameters under the below line to configure port `25`:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
```

We have some embedded devices on the field that can't speak TLS and can only *"submit"* emails through port `25`. This is why this port can use opurtunistic TLS but not mandatory TLS.

I already set up oportunistic TLS for the **inbound** requests i.e. email *"submission"* and email *"relay recieve"* like this:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtp
#
  -o smtpd_use_tls=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
  -o smtpd_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
  -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/server-rsa.cert
  -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/server-rsa.key
#
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

> **NOTE:**
> Parameters starting with `-o smtpd_` configure only **inbound**
> requests, while parameters starting with `-o smtp_` *(currently I have none)* configure
> **outbound** requests.

### Question:

Now I am wondering...

- Should I set mandatory TLS for **outbound** requests i.e. *"relay sending"* on port `25`? What problems could occur?
- What happens if I set mandatory TLS for **outbound** requests i.e. *"relay sending"* on port `25` and some destination server does not support mandatory TLS or oportunistic TLS on it's *"relay recieving"* port `25`?
- Is oportunistic TLS what should be set for **outbound** requests i.e. *"relay sending"* on port `25` to avoid problems?
- I know that oportunistic TLS is not 100% safe and I know it can be protected using DANE but who exactly DANE prottects? *"Relay sender"* or *"relay reciever"*? So should DANE be set for **inbound** or **outbound** requests?

Comment: If you make TLS mandatory for your server and a recipients mailserver doesn't support TLS then your messages won't be delivered and you should get a delivery error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need incoming port 25 for any other purposes than accepting email from the Internet: the port 465 is for (implicit TLS) submission and for outbound SMTP you use the port 25 of the receiving server.

Also, it's not a good idea to make TLS mandatory on port 25, as it breaks the backwards compatibility and, therefore, pretty much your whole email infrastructure. DANE ([RFC 6698](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6698)) is exactly for that: for letting the others know that you don't need that backwards compatibility, and being comfortable not to fallback to unencrypted connections even if someone (MitM) had removed the `250-STARTTLS` extension ([RFC 3207](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3207)).

Comment: If I compare parameters `smtp_tls_security_level` (**outbound**) and `smtpd_tls_security_level` (**inbound**) in the official Postfix [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) I can see that only first one supports DANE and later does not! What does that mean? Am I only protected by DANE if I send information, but not if I receive?!

Comment: If the sender supports DANE and you have published the `TLSA` records, the connection is protected by DANE. It's not used for receiver verifying senders but for senders verifying the receivers. Therefore, there's no reason for smtpd to support it.

Comment: I can not **guarantee** that even if I set `smtp_tls_security_level=dane` that my emails will be encrypted. If my server sends email to destination server that does not even support `STARTTLS` my opportunistic TLS will automatically remain unencrypted and I am sending unencrypted emails... This sucks! I would rather use mandatory TLS on port `25` and ignore recievers who do not support TLS.

Comment: By settings `smtp_tls_security_level=dane` you enforce encryption when the receiver has given permission to that. Also notice that DANE requires working DNSSEC. Of course you can enforce TLS without consent, but then you probably can't send email to everyone. Furthermore, many SMTP servers are still using self-signed certificates you can't distinguish from faked ones. How is that really any better than an unencrypted connection?

Comment: Don't get me wrong: in an ideal world 100% of email would be encrypted in transit and every SMTP server would have a valid certificate backed up with both DANE and PKI. I think we have the same goal here, but my approach is just a bit more patient.

Comment: Unfortunately I must totaly agree.